# std::function, template parameter T(X)

Tags: c++11, std-function

I'm wondering if anyone can please explain how, given types `T` and `X`, `std::function` takes  `T(X)` as a template parameter.

`int(double)` looks like the usual cast from `double` to `int`, so how is `std::function` parsing it as distinct types? 
I did search but didn't find anything that specifically addresses this question. Thanks!

Comment: `int(double)` is a function type. `int f(double)` would be declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can use partial template specialization. Look at this:

```
template <typename T>
class Func;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Func<R(Args...)>
{
public:
    Func(R(*fptr)(Args...)) {/*do something with fptr*/}
};
```

This class takes a single template parameter. But unless it matches `R(Args...)` (i.e. a function type returning R and taking zero or more args), there wont be a definition for the class.

```
int main() { Func<int> f; }
// error: aggregate 'Func<int> f' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

.

```
int func(double a) { return a+2; }
int main() { Func<int(double)> f = func; }
// ok
```

The specialization can now operate on `R` and `Args` to do its magic.

Note that `int(double)` is a function type. Since you cannot create raw function objects, you don't usually see this syntax outside the template world. If `T` is `int(double)` then `T*` is a function pointer just like `int(*)(double)`.

Comment: Thank you for that helpful response!